# How to highlight duplicate hashtags entered into textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
$(function() {
  $(".count-button").click(function() {
    // save the matches instead of immediately counting
    var text = $("textarea").val();

    var tags = text.match(/(?:#)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)/g) || [];

    // init empty array for holding unique matches
    var uTags = [];

    var dupTags = [];

    // loop through matches
    $.each(tags, function(index, value) {

      // if match is not in holding array, add it to holding array
      if (uTags.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        uTags.push(value);

      } else {

        dupTags.push(uTags);
        
        $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
      words: dupTags,
      caseSensitive: false
    });

      }

    });


    // get count from holding array which will only have one copy of each match
    var count = uTags.length;
    $('.text-well').html(count);

    var count2 = dupTags.length;
    $('.text-well-dup').html(count2);

  }).trigger('click');


  $(".reset-button").click(function() {
    $("textarea").val(' ');
    $('.text-well').html(0);
    $('.text-well-dup').html(0);
  }).trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.hashtagcounter.com/wp-content/themes/freedom-pro/js/custom/jquery.highlighttextarea.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://www.hashtagcounter.com/wp-content/themes/freedom-pro/css/jquery.highlighttextarea.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="textarea-well clearfix">
  <h3>Instagram Hashtag Counter</h3>
  <textarea class="textarea-main" rows="16"></textarea>
  <div class="buttons"><button class="count-button" type="button">Count</button><button class="reset-button" type="button">Reset</button></div>
  <div class="remaining-counter">Hashtags Counted: <span class="text-well">0</span></div>
  <div class="remaining-counter">Duplicates Counted: <span class="text-well-dup">0</span></div>

</div>
```

I am currently stuck and could do with some help.

I've build a hashtag counter which can be found at hashtagcounter.com and at the moment it is set to count hashtags and duplicate hashtags on the click of a button.

However, it would be really neat if it could also highlight the duplicate hashtags once the button is clicked too, so the user casn know which hashtags to remove.

I was attempting to highlight the dupTags array, however, this is not working. In fact chrome, gives back 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'

Comment: Please _show us_ what you actually tried (in regard to that highlighting library you mentioned), instead of just telling us that you were "unable" to make it work. [ask], [mre]

Comment: If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the code to include what I have tries. Apologies for not including it at the start

Comment: @mplungjan have updated the code now

Comment: Can't see how `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` is supposed to make any sense here - you placed this code _inside_ of `$(".count-button").click(...)`, so if jQuery was not know under the name `$`, you should have gotten that error way earlier already.

Comment: @CBroe it's unlikely, but possible if `$.noConfict()` is called after the doc.ready is initialised:  https://jsfiddle.net/xpsbqvow/1/  eg by another plugin or page framework (wordpress?)

Comment: @freedomn-m good point; although I think here it should rather have failed at `var text = $("textarea").val();` already then, if noconflict was set outside of this click handler, after the handler itself was added - and not only since `$('textarea').highlightTextarea(...)` was added.

Comment: @CBroe I don't for a minute think it's the case here.   Need a complete [mcve] that *demonstrates* the issue - as you requested an hour ago.

Comment: @CBroe I have added a code snippet

Comment: @freedomn-m I have added a code snippet. New to StackOverflow so not sure what the minimal repdocible example is

Comment: @TimothyDavis no worries - takes a while.   Just need the code to *demonstrate* the issue (I haven't checked yet)

Comment: Your snippet here now errors with `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highlightTextarea is not a function` - which is quite a different thing, than the error message you gave us earlier. So is the this one you actually got?

Comment: Your first issue is that jquery needs to be loaded before jquery plugins.   However, moving it doesn't seem to remove the error - but, copy+paste the highlight.min.js and the error goes away - so something strange going on with that script tag (though doesn't seem to do anything, just error goes away)

Comment: @CBroe Yes, my bad, that is the correct error

Comment: Did you try googling the error?  There are innumerable such duplicate questions already here on StackOverflow.  Please do some research, and stating "doesn't work" is hardly ever helpful.  Hope these suggestions improve your long-term experience here,

Comment: @Dexygen Hey, yeah I have spent the last several hours trying to find something on google which would help, however, did not find anything that either I could understand or that worked

Comment: @freedomn-m I have managed to fix the error using your advice, thanks for that. However as you mentioned none of the hashtags are being highlighted which is odd. On the main site, the highlights are showing, however, it appears that the textfield is duplicating itself when the button is clicked.

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Wrapped it in $(function() {})